# how do you get back sum('amount') for a paginated eloquent query In laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections, pagination

I have a model `Logbook` for pilot and my controller Return

`$this->log_book->orderBy('flight_date','asc')->paginate(18);`

I want to sum **total flight time** in each page.

total flight time for first page calculate from DB but for second page and next page , `$previous_total_page_time` should be total time of first page and for next page too.

I don't know how can save a variable temporary `$page_previous_total_time` and use it in second and next pages

flight time is saved as A Int (minutes in integer)

request is Get

[in this image you see my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r9He.jpg)

Comment: Can we see the "view" file? or at least a part of it? are you using a GET request or what?

Comment: I also want to see what you tried so far for "previous_total_page_time"

Comment: request is Get flight time is saved as a Int (minutes in integer)

Comment: @EbrahimMohammed what has a view file to do with database level logic?

Comment: Ahh. my bad. probably been sleepy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved this problem.**

```
$currentPage = $logs->currentPage();
 if ($currentPage == 1) {
  $totalPrevPages = $flight_total_time;
  $flightInsTimePrevPages = $flight_ins_time;
  $total_time=$totalPrevPages + $totalCurrentPage;
}
else {
     $total_time = $this->log_book->log()->orderBy('leg_date','asc')->limit($count * $currentPage)->sum('total_time') + $flight_total_time;
    $totalPrevPages = $total_time - $totalCurrentPage ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total flight time on each request. This is not tested but hypothetically it should work.

```
$logBook = $this->log_book->orderBy('flight_date','asc');

$logBookPagination = $logBook->paginate(18);

// change the offset value to a value that makes sense for you
$logBookFlightTime = $logBook->offset(0)->limit($logBookPagination->perPage() * $logBookPagination->currentPage())->sum('id'); // replace with your column

return [
   'logBook' => $logBookPagination,
   'totalFlightTime' => $logBookFlightTime
];
```

To explain what i am doing is, i am taking a slice of models from 0 - the current page and then adding the flight time of all those models.